# My program does not compare the two variables (first_choice and second_choice)

Tags: python

When ever I try to run and play the game, first_player (first_choice) always wins. After trying to figure it out I replace the first if statement with random print statement and it would print that every time. I don't understand what is wrong:

```
while True:

    import os

    print("Welcome to the rock, paper, sisers Game")
    first_player = input("Player 1 enter your name: ")
    second_player = input("Player 2 enter your name: ")
    print("Use p for paper, r for rock, and s for sisers")
    first_choice = str(input("{} Pick: ".format(first_player)))
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
    second_choice = str(input("{} Pick: ".format(second_player)))
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

    if (first_choice == "r" or "R") and (second_choice == "s" or "S"):
        print("{} Won!!!!!".format(first_player))

    elif (second_choice == "r" or "R") and (first_choice == "s" or "S"):
        print("{} Won!!!!!".format(second_player))

    elif first_choice == second_choice:
        print("It is a draw")

    elif (second_choice == "s" or "S") and (first_choice == "p" or "P"):
        print("{} Won!!!!!".format(second_player))

    elif (second_choice == "p" or "P") and (first_choice == "s" or "S"):
        print("{} Won!!!!!".format(first_player))

    elif (second_choice == "p" or "P") and (first_choice == "r", "R"):
        print("{} Won!!!!!".format(second_player))

    elif (second_choice == "r" or "R") and (first_choice == "p" or "P"):
        print("{} Won!!!!!".format(first_player))
```

Replace the first if statement print function:

```
while True:

    import os

    print("Welcome to the rock, paper, sisers Game")
    first_player = input("Player 1 enter your name: ")
    second_player = input("Player 2 enter your name: ")
    print("Use p for paper, r for rock, and s for sisers")
    first_choice = str(input("{} Pick: ".format(first_player)))
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
    second_choice = str(input("{} Pick: ".format(second_player)))
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

    if (first_choice == "r" or "R") and (second_choice == "s" or "S"):
      print("useless random text")

    elif (second_choice == "r" or "R") and (first_choice == "s" or "S"):
      print("{} Won!!!!!".format(second_player))

    elif first_choice == second_choice:
      print("It is a draw")

    elif (second_choice == "s" or "S") and (first_choice == "p" or "P"):
      print("{} Won!!!!!".format(second_player))

    elif (second_choice == "p" or "P") and (first_choice == "s" or "S"):
      print("{} Won!!!!!".format(first_player))

    elif (second_choice == "p" or "P") and (first_choice == "r", "R"):
      print("{} Won!!!!!".format(second_player))

    elif (second_choice == "r" or "R") and (first_choice == "p" or "P"):
      print("{} Won!!!!!".format(first_player))
```

Comment: Try rewriting your conditions as `if (first_choice == "r" or first_choice == "R") and (second_choice == "s" or second_choice == "S")`.

Comment: I only had a quick look but you are comparing wrong. `(first_choice == "r" or "R"` is always true because of the `or "R"` check if string "R" is empty. Use `(first_choice == "r" or first_choice == "R"`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do `if condition == value or another_value` in python. It will always be evaluated to True, since the `another_value` is non-empty for all of your cases.

You will have to evaluate them separately:

```
if condition == value or condition == another_value:
```

another way is to use `in` operator:

```
if condition in {value, another_value}:
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your if/elif statements like this:

> if ((first_choice == "r" or "R") and (second_choice == "s" or "S")):

It has to due with order of evaluation in python and it is only validating your first operation.

Comment: Your code does not seem to be correct. Maybe you meant something like `first_choice in ['r', 'R']` or `first_choise.lower() == 'r'`. Idem for the second condition.